# Get an output for column name and it's column number at the same time

Tags: r, names

I am trying to get the column name and number of columns that have `"NA"` in them, I have tried using this code

```
names(df)[sapply(df, anyNA)]
```

but it only gives me the column names and no the numbers,
any idea how to get an output for both?

Answer (score 2):

We may convert the logical vector to index with `which` and subset the index with `names` to get the column names

```
i1 <- sapply(df, anyNA)
which(i1)
names(df)[i1]
```

We may not need the `names(df)[i1]` as `which` gives a named vector of index though i.e

```
which(sapply(df, anyNA))
```

will be a single line code to give both column names and index

---

Or with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   summarise(across(where(anyNA), ~ match(cur_column(), names(df))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `which` with `colsums` of `NA`.

```
which(colSums(is.na(iris_na)) > 0)
# Sepal.Length Petal.Length 
#            1            3
```

---

*Data:*

```
iris_na <- iris
iris_na[c(1, 3)] <- lapply(iris_na[c(1, 3)], \(x) replace(x, sample(length(x), length(x)/10), NA_real_))
```